# Traverse through a certain month in Date with just a given integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Would it be possible to go to a certain month of the year with just a given integer. For example

```
date = Date.today
=> Wed, 30 Dec 2015
```

What if I want to go back to a certain month based on that date and I am just given a number let's say 7 which is July in the Date::MONTHNAMES so would it be possible to do something like

```
date = Date.today
=> Wed, 30 Dec 2015
date.go_to_month_of(7) # which will bring me back to July 30, 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it.  It's:

```
 date = Date.today
 date.change(:month => x)
```

Hope this helps you!